# How to disable expanding for some items in BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'd like to disable expandability for some items in the [ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15479026/2401535).

So far I know it can be done form [ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15479026/2401535) but I think it's not good to control what to show/why/where NOT from ListView - this task belongs to adapter and there I want to disable expandability.

So how to do it from a class which extends [BaseExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html)?

So far I've tried to set `convertView` visibility to `View.GONE` but it does not work (i.e. it shows some weird View, empty but not `View.GONE`)

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.system_status_child, parent, false);
    }

    Item item = systemStatus.get(groupPosition);

    if(item.isStatusOk()){
        convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((TextViewMuseo)convertView).setText(item.getChild_text());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

`system_status_child.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/system_status_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some text" />
```

Comment: Could you not just return a different blank view at the very beginning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return 0 as the children count for those groups:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if (groupPosition == 0 || groupPosition == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        // return normal children count
    }
}
```